# Counting consecutive values each three times in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, counter

I have this

```
df<-cbind(
t1=c(1,1,1),
t2=c(1,1,1),
t3=c(0,1,1),
t4=c(1,0,1),
t5=c(1,1,1),
t6=c(1,1,1),
t7=c(1,1,0),
t8=c(0,1,1),
t9=c(1,1,1))


> df
     t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
[1,]  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1
[2,]  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
[3,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
```

and I need to count the "ones" in each row in t3, t6 and t9.
Every time the counter reach 3 has to go back to zero and start over again.

In this case the results should be:

```
new_t3 = 0, 3, 3

new_t6 = 3, 2, 3

new_t9= 1, 3, 2
```

How can I count these consecutive "ones" values at t3, t6 and t9?
I've looked at rle but I'm still having trouble with it!

Many thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why the first value of new_t3 is 0 and not 2 ? isn't t3 preceded by two '1' ? Or am I not getting something ?

Comment: Also, you want to reset to zero every 3 elements, or only when the sum reaches 3 ? Please give more details of your algorithm...at the moment your expected result seems wrong according to your explanation...probably a step by step explanation for the first row could be enough

Comment: Fraid I can't make sense of the results you linked either.

Comment: the first value in t3 is 0 because the counter is empty. Every time gets a 0 at t3, t6 or t9 should start in zero independent of the 1's before. You are right, when sum reaches 3. Thank!

Comment: Ok... then the first value in t9 should be 2 ? because at t3 we have 0, then at t6 we have 3, but then there are two '1's before (and including) t9

Comment: the first value in new_t9 should be 1 because the counter should have it on it. It will be counting only the 1's after zero from t7. I know is very confusing. Thanks any way!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work (edited to fix counts ending with 0):

```
dat <- as.data.frame(df)
new_t3 <- c()
for(i in 1:3){
    if(dat[i,3] != 0){
        count <- rle(dat[i,1:3])
        new_t3 <- append(new_t3, count$length[count$values == 1])
    } else{
        new_t3 <- append(new_t3, 0)
    }
}
```

This loops through each row for the column `t1` to `t3` and uses the `rle` function to calculate the number of consecutive values. `count$length[count$values == 1]` accesses the consecutive count where the value equalled 1 in the object returned by `rle`.  You'd have to do this for each of the column groups you're counting, e.g.:

```
new_t6 <- c()
for(i in 1:3){
    if(dat[i,6] != 0){
        count <- rle(dat[i,4:6])
        new_t6 <- append(new_t6, count$length[count$values == 1])
    } else{
        new_t6 <- append(new_t6, 0)
    }
}
```

Or somehow wrap the loop in a function or nested for loop to automate over a table. But it looks like that returns the values in your example. Note that for `new_t9` this method returns `1  1 3 2` because there are two single `1` values (`1 0 1`) in the first row. You might have to do something to the `count` variable if you need to avoid that type of result (using `unique` or `max` perhaps).

Changing `df` to a dataframe object allowed `rle` to work, otherwise it couldn't access the values.

Comment: I don't get why in new_t3 you get **2,3,3**, the counter should be empty at that t3. Also, I understand the point at new_t9 and I will take only the right 1 in the df. Thank a lot!

Comment: new_t3 is 2,3,3 because there are two consecutive 1's in the first row (then 3 and 3 in rows 2 and 3). From the comments it looks like other people were expecting 2,3,3 as well -- were you not counting those two consecutive 1's in the first row?

Comment: Yes, I can't count the 1's before zero because the counter is empty in the first row at t3. Different story at t9. I know is kind of confusing (t3, t6 and t9 are my times of counting).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach using a good old for-loop combined with apply :

```
aggregateRow <- function(row){
  result <- rep(NA,length(row) %/% 3)
  cumul <- 0
  for(i in 1:length(row)){
    cumul <- cumul + row[i]
    if(i %% 3 == 0){
      if(row[i] == 0)
        cumul = 0
      if(cumul > 3)
        cumul = cumul - 3
      result[i %/% 3] = cumul
    }
  }
  return(result)
}

res <- t(apply(df,1,aggregateRow))
row.names(res) <- paste0('new_t',c(3,6,9)) # just to give names to the rows
> res
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
new_t3    0    3    2
new_t6    3    2    2
new_t9    3    3    2
```

Comment: Brillant!!... but in new_t3 (which considered the data from t7 to t9) the results should be 1, 3, 2.  The counter in every row when reaches 3 stops counting and get the maximun which is 3 and when find a zero start in zero.  Perhaps I'm not explaing well this process. Thank a lot any way!